# What does colon do in a javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, events, mouseevent

I saw in a javascript code written by a young guy this function

```
function foo(e:MouseEvent){
   ...
}
```

> I want to know what does **e:MouseEvent** do?

Comment: It's called a syntax error.

Comment: @Vohuman what does it mean

Comment: It breaks your script. That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure it is JavaScript, and not TypeScript, or Flow, or something with types that compiles to JavaScript?

Comment: It smells like one of those pseudo languages. It can be read as this parameter is an instance of `MouseEvent` constructor.

Comment: @elclanrs Actually i am not sure it just looks like javascript and i was wonder if there is something in javascript function parameter which i don't know

Comment: But it doesn't look just like JavaScript, this looks like many languages with functions and types to me. You are probably looking at code that's meant to be transpiled.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

'e:MouseEvent' is a named parameter with a type declaration in typescript. A colon is used in typescript parameters to bind a parameter to a specific type which, in this case, is type 'MouseEvent'.

e is often used as the parameter name for a javascript event. Given the type it's likely a function that responds to a click event.

You can read more details about the syntax for it under the 'Function Types' heading of TypeScript's official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html.